# Elasticsearch: enable debug logging on standalone node client

Tags: elasticsearch

Can anyone point out how one can enable debug-level logging for discovery on a standalone client using the Node client? I have the following code, trying to join a single-node remote cluster. The discovery times out after 30 seconds (yet transport works fine, and starting a bootstrapped ES node on this same host with master=false, data=false works perfectly).

```
val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().
put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", false).
put("node.data","false").
put("node.master","false").
put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts ", "myeshost").
build

val node = nodeBuilder().
loadConfigSettings(false).
settings(settings).
client(true).
node.
start
```

But this only results in:

```
...
[run-main-0] INFO org.elasticsearch.node - [Hebe] starting ...
[run-main-0] INFO org.elasticsearch.transport - [Hebe] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9301]},publish_address {inet[/10.60.35.37:9301]}
[run-main-0] WARN org.elasticsearch.discovery - [Hebe] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
...
```

I found this [doc article](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/logging.html) talking about dynamic changes to logger.discovery values, but this likely doesn't work on a standalone client since discovery happens well before the HTTP listener is started to even receive the update request. Adding 'put("logger.discovery","DEBUG")'  to the settings builder above didn't help either.

Any pointers are sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access the Log4J logger factory directly using this:

```
import org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j;

// add this before creating your client node.
Log4jESLoggerFactory.getLogger("discovery").setLevel("DEBUG");
```